# Composite Primary Key (Sqlite.Swift)

Tags: sqlite.swift

How can I create a table with a composite primary key with this library. For example:

```swift
CREATE TABLE something (
  column1, 
  column2, 
  column3, 
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);
```

The only example I see in the documentation is a primary key on single column:

```swift
try db.run(users.create { t in     
    t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
    t.column(email, unique: true)  
    t.column(name)                 
})
```

I tried the following but fails with an error (...table "" has more than one primary key) :

```swift
try db.run(tblTsMosStaged.create { t in
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedEventId, primaryKey: true)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedEventInstance, primaryKey: true)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedTaxId, primaryKey: true)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedRankId)
...
```

Or is this only possible via [Executing Arbitrary SQL](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#executing-arbitrary-sql)

Answer (score 4):

The [SQLite.swift documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#table-constraints) says:

> **Table Constraints**
>
> Additional constraints may be provided outside the scope of a single column using the following functions.
>
> - primaryKey adds a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint to the table. Unlike the column constraint, above, it supports all SQLite types, ascending and descending orders, and composite (multiple column) keys.
>
>   ```
>     t.primaryKey(email.asc, name)
>     // PRIMARY KEY("email" ASC, "name")
>   ```

```swift
 try db.run(tblTsMosStaged.create { t in
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedEventId)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedEventInstance)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedTaxId)
                        t.column(colTsMosStagedRankId)
//ADD this line
                        t.primaryKey(colTsMosStagedEventId, colTsMosStagedEventInstance, colTsMosStagedTaxId)
```